# VueRouter doesn't work properly in history mode - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, .htaccess, vue.js, vue-router

I am using Vue project as a Wordpress theme. I've created a simple router but when I enable `mode: 'history'` I receive blank site. I've tried to configure `.htaccess` file but with no effects. My project is in VueWP directory in XAMPP htdocs directory. With hash everything works properly. Where is the mistake?

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /VueWP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /VueWP/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This is my VueRouter:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Main from '../Components/Main';
import ArticlePage from '../Components/ArticlePage';
import Page from '../Components/Page';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Main',
            component: Main
        },
        {
            path: '/post/:url',
            name: 'ArticlePage',
            component: ArticlePage
        },
        {
            path: '/page/:url',
            name: 'Page',
            component: Page
        }
    ],

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `publicPath: '/'` in your routes file. Hope it works.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Main from '../Components/Main';
import ArticlePage from '../Components/ArticlePage';
import Page from '../Components/Page';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            publicPath: '/',
            name: 'Main',
            component: Main
        },
        {
            path: '/post/:url',
            publicPath: '/',
            name: 'ArticlePage',
            component: ArticlePage
        },
        {
            path: '/page/:url',
            publicPath: '/',
            name: 'Page',
            component: Page
        }
    ],

});
```